# How do I setup different ActionMailer Base smtp settings for development and production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, smtp, sendmail, actionmailer

I have ActionMailer working correctly in both production and development. I use different smtp settings for each environment, gmail for development and a SendGrid account through Heroku for production. I manually switch the settings in the setup_mail.rb file to work in development and then switch them back before pushing into production. This prevents my gmail password from becoming public on github as the SendGrid/Heroku settings do not require my password in the file:

development setup_mail.rb

```
    ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
      :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
      :port                 => 587,
      :domain               => "mysite.com",
      :user_name            => "me@mysite.com",
      :password             => 'mypassword',
      :authentication       => "plain",
      :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

production setup_mail.rb

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  :port           => '587',
  :authentication => :plain,
  :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
  :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
  :domain         => 'heroku.com'
}
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
```

I am concerned that I will accidentally push the development settings with my password to github. I'd like to stop switching settings manually to prevent this from happening. How do I setup different ActionMailer Base smtp settings for development and production? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have this setting in production.rb and development.rb, instead of having your password hard coded, you could use environment variables locally too, create a .env file in your project, which will be loaded when you `cd` in:

```
EMAIL=me@mysite.com
EMAIL_PASSWORD= mypassword
```

Use `ENV['EMAIL']` AND `ENV['EMAIL_PASSWORD']` in development.rb

Comment: Thanks, environment variables was the way to go. I ditched the gmail settings in favor of SendGrid in both development and production and my settings are safe. I found this [RailsApps Project Rails Environment Variables](http://railsapps.github.com/rails-environment-variables.html) to be very helpful as well as RailsCast #85 YAML Configurations (revised). There is also the Figaro Gem which I did not use but suspect would be useful here as well.